# Why is my granite still retaining a lot of water after sealing?

Tags: sealing, granite

I bought a new batch of beige granite countertops and they look great, have a good shine, but they are retaining moisture easily after sealing 3-4 times.  I use [Aquamix Gold](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-Aqua-Mix-Sealers-Choice-Gold-24-oz-Penetrating-Sealer-AMSC24Z/202907686) on all my other granite but doesn't seem to be doing the job here.  I am thinking since it is breathable that it is letting the water seep in and I am guessing my granite is pretty porous.  Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at polished granite with a magnifying glass, you'll see the tiny fissure and pock marks that allow moisture from water and other liquids to penetrate into it. Just because it's polished doesn't make it waterproof. One of my customers recently had picked out 3 prefabricated granite slabs but had to leave them in the granite yard for two weeks before I could pick them up. When I bought them, the slabs had darker edges and I was assured from the granite personnel that the darkness came from being exposed to the rain and that it would evaporate.  We went through a hot spell and by the time I picked up the slabs, the moisture had evaporated and the darkness from the moisture was gone. Don't seal your granite until you are sure the existing moisture has evaporated because it's kind of like painting over a dirty wall, sooner or later the coating will fail.  I don't buy my sealer from the big box stores. Go to a reputable tile or granite yard and get the best sealer you can afford and follow the application instructions. Personally, I use a product called "Rock Steel" and have had nothing but success with it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's porous, it's not granite. It may be marble or some other stone, but granite is too dense to take on any appreciable water. That's why it's used extensively for curbs and sidewalks in Vermont, where winter weather is REALLY COLD - if it took on moisture, that moisture would freeze and blow our curbs & sidewalks apart (a technique actually applied in certain quarries, where ice in drilled holes eliminates the need for explosives).

Comment: It is granite.  This specific granite is sold at big box, I have seen it at multiple tile shops and so on.  I am 120% sure it is granite.  Granite has a very wide range of being porous, hardness, other traits.  For instance if I went with a darker granite they are not nearly as porous and maybe what you are thinking of.

Comment: Interesting. We have a lot of beige granite patio blocks behind the house, some polished, some not (they were here when we bought the place). Despite many -30*F deep freezes, the polished ones retain their polish year to year, showing no sign of porosity. It MIGHT be the case that granite from other places - or even "cultured granite" - may be porous, but granite is generally considered to be nonporous stone. That, too, is why it lasts so very well as grave markers.

Comment: If it were completely nonporous why would I need to seal it?

Comment: You shouldn't need to - granite headstones are never sealed. I wonder if what you have isn't truly granite, but granitite?

Comment: Regardless... all this discussion isn't getting us any closer to the goal of getting your COUNTERTOP sealed. Have you tried a paste wax?

Comment: Looking for something more permanent since these are going in some remodels.

Comment: Oh, BOOGER. That does make it more difficult. Seems to me... you may be able to use an acrylic grout admix as a sealant. That should be nearly as permanent a sealant as you can find, with a ten-year life expectancy.

Comment: I'm a little perplexed too.  The granite grains should have zero porosity, but the grain boundaries can hold moisture in the lower-quality stuff.  Here's my suspicion: The stone was treated with something to protect it during transport or manufacture and was not properly removed.  That coating must be sensitive to water.  Find a low-visibility test spot and scrub with acetone and a granite scotch-brite pad and then re-seal.

Comment: It might also be that the surface is not polished very well and if you have the right tools and experience you can re-polish.  Or you can "polish" with a wax, but that's just a temporary fix.